# Synergy config dual monitors separately

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, xorg, synergy

In Synergy, is it possible to set up your config so that you have one server and one client, both with dual monitors, but the client machine has its monitors such that one is on the left of the server's left monitor, and the other is on the right of the server's right monitor? For example:

```
+----------+  +----------+  +----------+  +----------+
|  client  |  |  server  |  |  server  |  |  client  |
|  screen1 |  |  screen1 |  |  screen2 |  |  screen2 |
+----------+  +----------+  +----------+  +----------+
```

Hopefully my ASCII is good enough to understand. Both machines will be running Linux. If there's a way to do it by messing with xorg configs that would be perfectly acceptable too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I'm grasping what you are asking.  Synergy allows you to move your mouse and keyboard input to a separate PC regardless of where the displays for that PC are located.

If you want to set your screens up as noted above, simply move the monitors to those locations.

Apologies if I'm completely missing the point.

Comment: Well you have to tell synergy which client is in which direction of the others. But how would I tell it this configuration? The client is both to the left and right of the server. I imagine there's no default way to do this in synergy but I was hoping there might be an X11 hack or something that would get it to work. I'll probably ask this on unix.stackexchange

Comment: That doesn't particularly matter, it's only so if you mouse off the left side of the screen, it switches to the left desktop and vice versa.  My config has both of my other screens (seperate PCs) set to the right while I have one physically on the left, it just means I mouse the top right and bottom right to reach different PCs.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality won't be available in an intuitive way until per-monitor configuration with uneven edges hits in Synergy 2.1 (2.0 is still in beta at time of writing, seven years after the OP).

You should be able to fake this though.

For your specific use case, put client screen 1 to the right of client screen 2 in xorg and then set up synergy to wrap around with client to both the left and right of server.

Comment: You should be able to fake it or you know you can and you've tried and confirmed? Just curious if you are guessing or making a statement you know is accurate and will work?

Comment: I have not tried and confirmed because I do not have the same setup at this point in time.  I have had a similar layout working in the past using the above method, and I'm waiting on 2.1 to be able to handle my current portrait / 2 stacked landscape / portrait layout.